# How to launch an X server on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, x11, rdp

Take an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2 (w/ MATE DE) and say we want to initiate an X session on it.

One way to go about it would be through **RDP.** We could set a password for *ec2-user* and *generate a TLS certificate*:

```
sudo passwd ec2-user

sudo openssl req -x509 -sha384 -newkey rsa:3072 -nodes -keyout /etc/xrdp/key.pem -out /etc/xrdp/cert.pem -days 365
```

Then start an RDP session and log in as ec2-user with the password we set, and an X session would have been initiated. When running `ls -a` on *home/ec2-user* we would see the newly created `.Xauthority` file.

How can we do the same through an **SSH session** *or* **directly on the machine** using something like [EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)?